# qsort() giving random results

Tags: c, sorting

In the above program, I create an array of pointers to char using malloc and then attempt to sort those "strings" using qsort. I'm getting incorrect results. More importantly, I'm getting different results every time I run the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 
#define MAXCHARS 1000 
int ballin_compare(const void *, const void *); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *linebuffer, **pointbuffer; 
    FILE *fp;
        int i = 0;  

        if(argc < 2 || (fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
            return 1; 

    linebuffer = (char *)malloc(MAXCHARS); 
    pointbuffer = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAXLINE); 

    while(i < MAXLINE && fgets(linebuffer, MAXCHARS, fp) != NULL){
        pointbuffer[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(linebuffer)); 
        strcpy(pointbuffer[i++], linebuffer); 
    }

    free(linebuffer); 
    qsort(pointbuffer, i, sizeof(char *), ballin_compare); 

    fclose(fp); 
    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "w")) == NULL)
        return 1; 

    int x; 
    for(x = 0; x < i; x++)
        fputs(pointbuffer[x], fp);

    fclose(fp); 
    printf("%s sorted successfully", argv[1]);
        return 0;   
}



int ballin_compare(const void *c, const void *d){
    char *a = (char *)c; 
    char *b = (char *)d; 

    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] && b[i] && a[i] == b[i])
        i++; 

    if(a[i] < b[i])
       return -1; 
    if(a[i] > b[i])
       return 1; 

    return 0; 
}
```

My guess is that I messed up my strcmp equivalent. Any ideas where my comparisons went wrong?

Comment: ...why did you reimplement `strcmp`? Did you try it with just `strcmp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `qsort` passes in *pointers* to the elements of your array. Since your array elements are of type `char *`, your comparison function receives **`char **`** inputs. As currently written, you are comparing addresses as if they were strings, which naturally results in nonsense results.

You should write

```
const char *a = *(const char **)c;
const char *b = *(const char **)d;
```

in `ballin_compare`.

Comment: ***`const`*** `char *`. Anyway: one thing I will probably never understand nor tolerate is this: *why don't people read the funny manual???*

Comment: I don't know. Wish there was a close option for "should've read the manual". Anyway, in this case he actually has `char *`s allocated from a buffer, so the `const` isn't necessary (though it should still be used for a sort).

Comment: Also FYI, even if your compare function is wrong in a totally deterministic way, your results will be random because a properly implemented quicksort chooses pivots randomly.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *a = (char *)c;
```

is doubly wrong.

First, in C, you don't need the cast, and if unnecessary, casts should be avoided.

Second, you don't have the **actual** strings passed to your comparator function. You have **pointers** to them (think about that: it would be impossible to pass down any type of object to the comparator function when implemening a generic sort function such as qsort, because the objects to be compares can be of any type and size). So what you really want is

```
const char *a = *(const char **)c;
```

Also notice the use of `const` - it's not a coincidence it's there. Furthermore, simply use

```
return strcmp(a, b);
```

you don't need (and you better not) reinvent the wheel.

Also, [read the funny manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) - all of this is written down clearly in there.